# After 13.04 Install: Unable to Enter Online Accounts

Tags: 13.04, empathy, online-accounts, system-settings

In System Settings after an upgrade from 12.10 to 13.04 I am not longer able to add Online Accounts. (I noticed this after launching Empathy, which prompted me: "You need to set up an account to see contacts here.") I had an AIM account already configured but was not able to see my AIM contacts. I tried to remove the AIM account and re-add, but the System Settings panes for Online Accounts does not have any fields for adding account info, just: "Please enter your account details Cancel/Done".

Comment: UPDATE: The only Online Account that I cannot enter is AIM.

Comment: There is some bug report to this: [launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/1159411)

Answer (score 0):

Online accounts — and particularly online contacts — don't work properly under 13.04.

Annoying details: [Bug #1024606 “gnome-contacts stopped showing contacts from Googl...” : Bugs : “gnome-contacts” package : Ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-contacts/+bug/1024606)